# Is it possible to add watermark to QR code generated by google charts api

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, google-visualization, qr-code

Is it possible to add watermark to QR code generated by google charts api using jquery or cakephp.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't watermark a QR code. Instead, I'd probably watermark the data I was encoding in the QR code in some way.

For example, if you're encoding a URL, could you, for example, change the URL from "http://example.com/foo" to "http://example.com/foo?watermark-referrer=www-yourdomain-com-whatever"? Then there's still an indication that the QR code is yours, but you don't have to risk breaking the QR image itself.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the only way to do that is saving the image generated by google charts on your server, and then add the watermark vi GD or imagemagick.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery option is to just place a watermark image on top of the one that Google Charts makes, but the original will still be available.

A PHP option is generate the QR image via a curl request, read the bitmap data in, muck with it via GD or ImageMagick, then save it somewhere and display it.

The watermark may interfere with a scanning algorithm, though, especially when read with a bad camera.

Comment: If you modify the url used to generate the QR from Google, you can force it to use a higher error correction setting. This will make it more tolerant to parts of it being obscured.  Add this "&chld=H|4" For example: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=H|4&chl=Hello+world.  Details here: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/qr_codes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should test the QR code with watermark, because there is a big chance that lots of reader won't recognize.